# How can I show only the services of that category using select option of html in vue js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, vue-component

I have several categories as hotel, healthcare etc. So, when I select hotel, only the services of category hotel should be loaded. Now when I am selecting a particular category all the services are loading?

This is my vue js script. It has two urls one to get all categories and other to get all services.

```
<script>
searchContent = new Vue({
        el: "#searchContent",
        data: {
          vector: {}
        }
      });
categories = new Vue({
    el: '#categories',
    data: {
        articles: [],
        services: [],
        category: 0,
        subcategory: 0,
        content: false
    },
      watch: {
           subcategory: function(e) {
            this.prefetch();
          },
           category: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.subcategory = 0;
            $.ajax({
              url: "https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_all_services/",
              data: {
                'service': self.id
              },
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "JSON",
              success: function(e) {
                self.services = e;
                self.prefetch();
              }
            });
          },
      },

    mounted() {
        var vm = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_all_category/",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(e) {
                 vm.articles = e;
                console.log(e.articles)

            },
        });
    },

          methods: {
          prefetch: function() {
            var filter = {};
            filter['category'] = this.category;
            filter['subcategory'] = this.subcategory;
            if (this.content !== false)
              this.content.abort()
            this.content = $.ajax({
              'url': 'https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/filter/',
              data: filter,
              dataType: "JSON",
              type: "POST",
              success: function(e) {
                 window.searchContent.vector = e.data;
                console.log(e);
              }
            })
          }
        }

})
</script>
```

This is my html code

```
<div class="m-select">
<select class="" v-model="category" name=category>

<option value="">Select Service</option>
<option style="padding-left: 10px;" v-for="post in articles"v-bind:value="post.name" >{{post.name}}</option>

</select>
 </div>

<div class="m-select">
<select class="" v-model="subcategory" name="subcategory">
<option value="">Select Services</option>
<option v-for=" so in services" v-bind:value="so.name">{{so.name}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

JSON data for category: url https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_all_category/

```
[{"name": "Health care", "cat_id": 1}, {"name": "Education", "cat_id": 2}, {"name": "Bakery", "cat_id": 3}, {"name": "Software company", "cat_id": 4}, {"name": "Automobile", "cat_id": 5}, {"name": "Agriculture", "cat_id": 6}, {"name": "Marketing", "cat_id": 7}, {"name": "Multimedia", "cat_id": 8}, {"name": "Electrical Shop", "cat_id": 9}, {"name": "AutoTaxi", "cat_id": 10}, {"name": "Workshop", "cat_id": 11}, {"name": "Engineering Work", "cat_id": 12}, {"name": "Medical Shop", "cat_id": 13}, {"name": "Lathe", "cat_id": 14}, {"name": "Hotel", "cat_id": 15}]
```

JSON data for services is: url https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_all_services/

```
[{"name": "Eye clinic", "cat_id": 1, "sub_cat_id": 1}, {"name": "Homeo pathy", "cat_id": 1, "sub_cat_id": 2}, {"name": "Arts college", "cat_id": 2, "sub_cat_id": 3}, {"name": "Engineering", "cat_id": 2, "sub_cat_id": 4}, {"name": "Web development", "cat_id": 4, "sub_cat_id": 5}, {"name": "Wood lathe", "cat_id": 14, "sub_cat_id": 6}, {"name": "Steel lathe", "cat_id": 14, "sub_cat_id": 7}, {"name": "Steel lathe", "cat_id": 14, "sub_cat_id": 8}, {"name": "Hotel", "cat_id": 15, "sub_cat_id": 9}, {"name": "non veg hotels", "cat_id": 15, "sub_cat_id": 10}, {"name": "Veg Hotel", "cat_id": 15, "sub_cat_id": 11}, {"name": "Medicalshop", "cat_id": 13, "sub_cat_id": 12}, {"name": "Engineering Works", "cat_id": 12, "sub_cat_id": 13}, {"name": "Two Wheeler Workshop", "cat_id": 11, "sub_cat_id": 14}, {"name": "Four wheel workshop", "cat_id": 11, "sub_cat_id": 15}, {"name": "Auto Taxi", "cat_id": 10, "sub_cat_id": 16}, {"name": "Car", "cat_id": -1, "sub_cat_id": 17}, {"name": "Car", "cat_id": 10, "sub_cat_id": 18}, {"name": "Rent a Car", "cat_id": 10, "sub_cat_id": 19}, {"name": "electrical shop", "cat_id": 9, "sub_cat_id": 20}]
```

So, when I select category education, only services related to education be loaded.. How can I achieve the same using vues js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**METHOD 1** :
You could have an API in the back-end which returns services based on category id. i.e. you should be able to pass in the category id and it should return the services based on this category id. And then make a call to this API instead of `get_all_services` which you're doing right now.

**METHOD 2** :
Filter items based on `cat_id` from the result of all services on the front-end inside the watch handler for `category` (See added code below with comment) - [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/wbbza4w1/2/)

```
watch: {
           subcategory: function(e) {
            this.prefetch();
          },
           category: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.subcategory = 0;
            $.ajax({
              url: "https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_all_services/",
              data: {
                'service': self.id
              },
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "JSON",
              success: function(e) {
                let categoryIdArray = self.articles.filter(x=>x.name==self.category);
                self.services = e.filter(x=>x.cat_id==categoryIdArray[0].cat_id); // Filter items based on category id
                self.prefetch();
              }
            });
          },
      },
```

Comment: Sir, Thanks for the help.. I tried this.. but I am not able to load any services

Comment: Can you add the output of `console.log(e);` in the success handler just above the edited line and `console.log(self.services)` just below it and add it to the original question?

Comment: Also, please check my latest edit - `self.category` instead of `category` in the edited line and try again with that

Comment: @coder Have you REST service implemented on backend? Can you request something like this: "https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/services/cat_id/1/"? Or all you have are these two links for all categories and all services?

Comment: @Vandesh just a minute.. I am checking

Comment: @WaldemarIce I have this two links sir

Comment: @Vandesh No sir, I am not able to select any services

Comment: Can you post the output of `console.log`s that I mentioned?

Comment: @coder Not, you have not ;) You HAVE REST implemented :) And this changes whole game. You are able requesting services only for particular category. Very easy way... Do you want complete, working example how to do it the right way?

Comment: @Vandesh sir.. that complete list is loading

Comment: @Vandesh (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{name: "Eye clinic", cat_id: 1, sub_cat_id: 1}
1
:
{name: "Homeo pathy", cat_id: 1, sub_cat_id: 2}
2
:
{name: "Arts college", cat_id: 2, sub_cat_id: 3}
3
:
{name: "Engineering", cat_id: 2, sub_cat_id: 4}
4
:
{name: "Web development", cat_id: 4, sub_cat_id: 5}
5
:
19
:
{name: "electrical shop", cat_id: 9, sub_cat_id: 20}
length
:
20
__proto__
:
Array(0)

Comment: this is for `console.log(e)`, yes? What about `console.log(self.services)`? And also for `console.log(self.category)`

Comment: it was for console.log(e)

Comment: for console.log(self.category) Health care

Comment: for console.log(self.services) [__ob__: Observer]

Comment: @Vandesh I am not able to load services now.. That's why this happens

Comment: @WaldemarIce Canyou suggest a solution in this way.. It will be very helpful for me

Comment: @Vandesh Sir, that camparison is not working I think

Comment: @WaldemarIce Thanku Sir, for your helping mentality

Comment: We need to find the category id first. 
Check the updated code and JSFiddle link in the answer

Comment: @coder You are welcome. Read my answer for correct approach.

Comment: @Vandesh sir, this is the error I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cat_id' of undefined
    at self.services.e.filter.x (searchnewe.php:778)
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (searchnewe.php:778)
    at n (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d (jquery.min.js:4)
self.services.e.filter.x @ searchnewe.php:778
success @ searchnewe.php:778

Comment: Please check your code again, it seems you're writing `self.services.e.filter...` instead of `self.services = e.filter ...`

Comment: Its worked fine for me.. Thank you for the help.. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Vandesh Your approach is a bit cumbersome. There is no need for watchers for example. If Coder accepted it, ok, but I would not do it.

Comment: Given that he has no APIs for getting services based on categories, it needs to be handled on the front-end. And sure, one could use `v-on:change=changeHandler` instead of having watchers. But, according to his implementation, I don't see a problem with my answer.

Comment: I have already mentioned the other approach (what you're saying) in METHOD 1. So, in case there is an API available, that can be used as well.

Comment: Can I ask you a doubt sir.. When I am searching (as my above code) I get the results as json data (ie all the search results.. there will be many search reults). So, when I click on a particular search item.. how can I go to another page and print details of it?? Can you please help me with it

Comment: @coder Please post it in another question with the code that you've tried and if you're facing any problem, you can always get help on StackOverflow  :)

Answer (score 4):

You are using API wrong way. Rewrite your app this way:

1. Load all categories with this api call:
   https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_all_category/

You will obtain all categories, structure like this:

```
[
  {"name": "Health care", "cat_id": 1},
  {"name": "Education", "cat_id": 2},
  // etc
]
```

2. Create select with options this way:

   <option :value="category.cat_id>

   {{ category.name }}

   </option>
3. Let you select listening on change event.

In onchange callback load JUST CATEGORIES FOR SELECTED CATEGORY ID, INSTEAD OF ALL CATEGORIES. For example, for cat_id 1 make this api call:
https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_services_of/1

You will obtain services only for selected id:

```
[
  {"name": "Eye clinic", "cat_id": 1, "sub_cat_id": 1},
  {"name": "Homeo pathy", "cat_id": 1, "sub_cat_id": 2}
]
```

4. And now, as last step, fill your second select with options based on this json...

I like coding, so just for fun, there is working example with your API :)

```js
var store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    categories: [],
    services: []
  },
  actions: {
    async loadOptions ({state}, data) {
      var response = await fetch(data.src + data.id)
      state[data.to] = await response.json()
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('my-selector', {
  template: '#my-selector',
  methods: {
    loadServices (ev) {
      this.$store.dispatch('loadOptions', {
        to: 'services',
        src: 'https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_services_of/',
        id: ev.target.value
      })
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('loadOptions', {
      to: 'categories',
      src: 'https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_all_category/',
      id: ''
    })
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <my-selector></my-selector>
</div>

<template id="my-selector">
  <div>
    <select @change="loadServices">
      <option value="0" selected>Select category</option>
      <option
        v-for="category in $store.state.categories"
        :key="category.cat_id"
        :value="category.cat_id"
      >
        {{ category.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select>
      <option value="0" selected>Select service</option>
      <option
        v-for="service in $store.state.services"
        :key="service.sub_cat_id"
        :value="service.sub_cat_id"
      >
        {{ service.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.0.1/dist/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.3/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @coder Take a look for added example in my answer. I think it can inspire you to simplify your actual code.

Comment: Can I ask you a doubt sir.. When I am searching (as my above code) I get the results as json data (ie all the search results.. there will be many search reults). So, when I click on a particular search item.. how can I go to another page and print details of it?? Can you please help me with it

Comment: Im not sure... Usually, its up to you to implement pagination and it this needs  individual approach, based on api possibilities. There is no universal, simple solution.

Comment: hello sir.. are you there

Comment: Can you please look into this issue.. I am really stuck with this.